# npm install doesn't install latest package on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I try to install the following dependencies:

`npm install --production objection@^1.0.0 knex@^0.14.3 pg@^4.4.0`

on Linux I get (*expected* versions):

```
+-- knex@0.14.6
+-- objection@1.1.8
`-- pg@4.5.7
```

The same command ran on Windows 10:

```
+-- knex@0.14.3
+-- objection@1.0.0
`-- pg@4.4.0
```

I checked what version I get back from the repository, for example: `npm view knex` and all is there: `'0.14.6': '2018-04-12T08:03:59.497Z'`

Why `npm install` on Windows is **not** pulling the latest dependencies (as allowed by the caret)?

Both on Windows and Linux I use npm v4.6.1.

Comment: is there a package-lock.json? If so, delete it and try installing again.

Comment: I use npm v4.6.1 (both windows and linux) and there is no `package-lock.json`.

Comment: can you try to update npm to a recent version and try again